# How to number sections starting from zero? (KOMA-Script)

Tags: sectioning, numbering, koma-script

I use KOMA-Script's `scrartcl` document class. I'd like the sections of the article to be numbered starting from zero. How can this be achieved? ([This post](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7800) claims that KOMA-Script has a built-in feature for this.)

Comment: Just like you would with `article`: add `\setcounter{section}{-1}` to your preamble.

Comment: @Werner: [This post](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7800) claims that KOMA-Script has a built-in feature for this.

Comment: @EvanAad I think the comment about built-in features refers to the _second_ solution proposed. (The author of that post writes 'This solution', not 'These solutions'.) The KOMA classes indeed provide the macros `\addchap` and `\addsec`, which automatically take care of the table of contents. But as far as starting the chapter/section from 0, I agree with the duplicate.

Comment: Before all of this, one should think of the sense to start at zero. I don't know any rational reason to start at Zero.

Comment: Mhhh, I also think that the inbuilt solution comment does not refer to starting counting at 0 but rather to unnumbered sections/chapters. Basically `\setcounter{section}{-1}` is so short already, that another solution built specifically into the document class could hardly be shorter or more elegant.

Comment: @moewe: OK. If Werner, campa and you have the same interpretation, and say there is no built-in KOMA-Script way to do it, I accept it. Therefore, I agree that my question is a duplicate.